# how to set the image position and size of image that inserted in navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

actually I don't know the correct way how to make an image inside the navigation bar like this, either using navigation controller or by using custom view by myself

[image]

I need to insert these 2 image as bar button and image title
[image]
[image]

so I tried to use navigation controller and insert an image in `viewDidLoad` like the code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // insert image title
        let aspectRatio : CGFloat = 0.25
        let widthOfImageHeader = view.frame.width * 0.5
        let heightOfImageHeader = widthOfImageHeader * aspectRatio

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthOfImageHeader, height: heightOfImageHeader))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "testImage2")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView


         // set bar button image
         //create a new button
         let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
         //set image for button
         button.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburgerIcon"), for: .normal)

         //set frame
         button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 51)

         let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
          //assign button to navigationbar
          self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }


}
```

but the result is like the image below:
[image]

the position of image title is not exactly in the center for iPhone 5s and bar button seems a little bit off in the right.

and if I assign the image right bar button, using

```
    /

/create a left button
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        //set image for button
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburgerIcon"), for: .normal)

        //set frame
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 51)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

        //create a right button
        let button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        //set image for button
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "backButton"), for: .normal)

        //set frame
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 51)

        let barRightButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barRightButton
```

the result is even weirder

[image]

one of the button dissapears, the hamburger icon that should be on the left, now in the right

it will be far easier if I use custom view, but...is it weird if I use custom view that use like navigation bar? I am new in iOS Developer. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the exact image do you want to put at the title of the navigation bar? Is it the "info kehadiran" in the image above?

Comment: yes, actually I just try using different image. but I expect the result will be the same since I specify the width and height. but the position is not exactly in the center

Comment: Okay, but can you share too what image do you want to put inside the navBar? Of course you can't put any image with any size you want there.

Comment: thanks Glenn, I update the question with the image

Comment: Check my answer below :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here's what I usually do in a project with such kind of requirements (image at the navBar's title, and custom bar button items).

To answer first your question, you can actually do whatever you want.

1. Have indeed a custom view while having your viewController embedded inside a `UINavigationController`. But be sure to hide the navBar.
2. Have a visible navBar and viewContorller embedded in `UINavigationController`.

The ideal way for me is the latter.

The sample project below was made using my own old framework: https://github.com/glennposadas/gpkit-ios

You can copy any pieces of codes from that framework, modify/rename everything on it, and put in your production project.

If you want the result below, here's how I do it:

```
import GPKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    internal lazy var button_Close: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ham"), for: .normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: -30, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hamburger(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    // MARK: - Functions
    // MARK: Overrides

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GPLog(classSender: self, log: "viewDidLoad!")

        // Title View Test: -

        let navBarImage = UIImage(named: "ic_logo_navbar")!
        self.setNavBarTitleWithFeedback(image: navBarImage, navBarTintColor: .white)

        self.makeNavBarColor(color: UIColor.colorWithRGBHex(0x332F39), itemsTintColor: .white)

        // Barbutton

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.button_Close)
        self.button_Close.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55.0, height: 44.0)
        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            negativeSpacer.width = -30
        }
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, barButton]
    }
}

extension ViewController: GPTitleViewDelegate {
    func gpTitleView(userDidTapTitleView gpTitleView: GPTitleView) {
        GPLog(classSender: self, log: "userDidTapTitleView")
    }

    func gpTitleView(userDidFinishLongPress gpTitleView: GPTitleView) {
        GPLog(classSender: self, log: "userDidFinishLongPress")
    }
}
```

**Result:**
I don't have your hex color, so it looks ugly.

[image]

I hope thish elps.